# Does cache line flush write the whole line to the memory?

Tags: caching, assembly, flush

When a dirty cache line is flushed (because of any reason), is the whole cache line written to the memory or CPU tracks down which words got written to and reduces the number of memory writes?

If this differs among architectures, I'm primarily interested in knowing this for Blackfin, but it would be nice to hear practices in x86, ARM, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generally if you have a write buffer it flushes through the write buffer (entire cache line).  Then the write buffer at some point completes the writes to ram.  I have not heard of a cache that keeps track per item within a line which parts are dirty or not, that is why you have a cache line.  So for the cases I have heard of the whole line goes out.  Another point is that it is not uncommon for the slow memory on the back side of a cache DDR for example, is accessed through some fixed width, 32 bits at a time 64 bits at a time 128 bits at a time, or each part is at that width and there are multiple parts.  That kind of thing, so to avoid a read-modify-write you want to write in complete ram width sizes.  Cache lines are multiples of that, sure, and the opportunity to not do writes is there.  Also if there is ecc on that ram then you need to write a whole ecc line at once to avoid a read-modify write.

You would need a dirty bit per writeable item in the cache line so that would multiply the dirty bit storage bu some amount, that may or may not have a real impact on size or cost, etc.  There may or may not be an overhead on the ram side per transaction and it may be cheaper to do a multi word transaction rather than even two separate transactions, so this scheme might create a performance hit rather than boost (same problem inside the write buffer, instead of one transaction with a start address and length, now multiple transactions).

It just seems like a lot of work for something that may or may not result in a gain.  If you find one that does please post it here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm dusting off my cobwebby computer architecture knowledge from classes taken 15 years ago -- please be kind if I'm totally wrong.

I seem to remember that x86, MIPS and Motorola, the whole line gets written.  This is because the cache line is the same as the bus width (except in very odd circumstances, such as the moldy old 386-SX line which was a 32-bit architecture with a 16-bit bus), so there's no point in trying to do word-wise optimization, the whole line is going to be written anyway.

I can't imagine any scenario in which a hardware architecture of any kind would do anything different, but I've been known to be wrong in the past.